# Change Caret Color in textbox

Tags: vb.net, colors, caret

I use this code to create a caret in a textbox (vb.net):

```
Private Declare Function CreateCaret Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hBitmap As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DestroyCaret Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function SetCaretBlinkTime Lib "user32" (ByVal wMSeconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetCaretPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ShowCaret Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function HideCaret Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Sub txtOutput_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtOutput.GotFocus
    CreateCaret(txtOutput.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 9, 12)
    ShowCaret(txtOutput.Handle)
End Sub
```

Is it possible to change the color of the caret?

Comment: I think you could do it if it were a `RichTextbox`

Comment: didn't work.Now I have a bigger problem,it shows me an error: PInvokestackImbalance has detected a problem

Comment: Can you provide the full code to display the caret? I can't run your example above.

Comment: Nevermind... you don't need a RichTextbox. Here, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is your PInvoke functions aren't declared properly. Look them up and match them with http://pinvoke.net/.

The calls to create the caret will take a bitmap handle. So depending on what your caret looks like, you just need to create a bitmap and pass it to the `CreateCaret` function to change it's color. Here's some (very) rough code I used to change the caret color of a regular textbox. Just note that I only changed `CreateCaret` and `ShowCaret` to the proper signatures from http://www.pinvoke.net. You will have to change the rest.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Function CreateCaret Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hBitmap As IntPtr, ByVal nWidth As Integer, ByVal nHeight As Integer) As Boolean
    Private Declare Function DestroyCaret Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function SetCaretBlinkTime Lib "user32" (ByVal wMSeconds As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetCaretPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ShowCaret Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
    Private Declare Function HideCaret Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

    Private caretBitmap as Bitmap
    Private Sub txtOutput_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtOutput.GotFocus
        If caretBitmap Is Nothing Then
            caretBitmap = CreateCaretBitmap()
        End If
        CreateCaret(txtOutput.Handle, caretBitmap.GetHbitmap(), 5, 10)
        ShowCaret(txtOutput.Handle)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Function CreateCaretBitmap() As Bitmap
        Dim flag As New Bitmap(5, 5)
        Dim flagGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(flag)

        flagGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Chartreuse, 0, 0, 5, 10)
        Return flag

    End Function
End Class
```

You can create the bitmap however you want obviously.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I solved the problem before I saw this.nvm.Thanks for the help anyways.I'll mark your answer :D